# Delete lines from a file matching first 2 fields from a second file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose I have `setA.txt`:

```
a|b|0.1
c|d|0.2
b|a|0.3
```

and I also have `setB.txt`:

```
c|d|200
a|b|100
```

Now I want to delete from `setA.txt` lines that have the same first 2 fields with `setB.txt`, so the output should be:

```
b|a|0.3
```

I tried:

```
comm -23 <(sort setA.txt) <(sort setB.txt)
```

But the equality is defined for whole line, so it won't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F\| 'FNR==NR{seen[$1,$2]=1;next;} !seen[$1,$2]' setB.txt setA.txt
b|a|0.3
```

This reads through `setB.txt` just once, extracts the needed information from it, and then reads through `setA.txt` while deciding which lines to print.

#### How it works

- `-F\|`

  This sets the field separator to a vertical bar, `|`.
- `FNR==NR{seen[$1,$2]=1;next;}`

  FNR is the number of lines read so far from the current file and NR is the total number of lines read.  Thus, when `FNR==NR`, we are reading the first file, `setB.txt`.  If so, set the value of associative array `seen` to true, `1`, for the key consisting of fields one and two.  Lastly, skip the rest of the commands and start over on the `next` line.
- `!seen[$1,$2]`

  If we get to this command, we are working on the second file, `setA.txt`.  Since `!` means negation, the condition is true if `seen[$1,$2]` is false which means that this combination of fields one and two was not in `setB.txt`.  If so, then the default action is performed which is to print the line.

Comment: He might want to create a script that does that and then sends the output to a file if he so chooses.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
sed -n 's#\(^[^|]*|[^|]*\)|.*#/^\1/d#p' setB.txt |sed -f- setA.txt
```

How this works:

```
sed -n 's#\(^[^|]*|[^|]*\)|.*#/^\1/d#p'
```

generates an output:

```
/^c|d/d
/^a|b/d
```

which is then used as a `sed` script for the next `sed` after the pipe and outputs:

```
b|a|0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

`(IFS=$'|'; cat setA.txt | while read x y z; do grep -q -P "\Q$x|$y|\E" setB.txt || echo "$x|$y|$z"; done; )`

explanation: grep -q means only test if grep can find the regexp, but do not output, -P means use Perl syntax, so that the `|` is matched as is because the `\Q..\E` struct.

`IFS=$'|'` will make bash to use `|` instead of the spaces (SPC, TAB, etc.) as token separator.

Comment: No upvote: This is very inefficient because it reads the entire `setB.txt` for every input line in `setA.txt`. (Well, with `grep -q`, not the entire file on every iteration, in the best case.)